# How to convert from docx to pdf with a python function (WINDOWS)?

Tags: python, ms-word, converters, comtypes

I am working on an env with a python function to convert docx to pdf files. I'm using postman to send base64. Then I mount the docx file (everything works yet), but when it converts the docx file into pdf, an error shows up. I'm thinking that is because I do not have Office on my env? How can I fix it without having office? Thanks.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client
import pythoncom
import uuid
import requests
from docx import Document
import base64
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  bytesDoc = req.get_json()['base']

  path = '/users/echornet/pruebas/'
  newFile = open(path + 'prueba.docx','wb')
  newFile.write(base64.b64decode(bytesDoc))

  newFile.close()
  wdFormatPDF = 17

  out_file = path + 'prueba.pdf'
  word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')

  doc = word.Documents.Open(newFile)
  doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
  doc.Close()
```

### This is the error I'm getting. I get the docx created from base64, but no conversion.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.FunConverter. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
>   Exception: AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.Word' has no attribute
>   '_Application' Stack:   File
>   "C:\PruebaFunction\ConvEnv\lib\site-packages\azure\functions_worker\dispatcher.py",
>   line 288, in _handle__invocation_request
>       self.**run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)   File "C:\Users\echornet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py",
>   line 55, in run
>       result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "C:\PruebaFunction\ConvEnv\lib\site-packages\azure\functions_worker\dispatcher.py",
>   line 347, in __run_sync_func
>       return func(**params)   File "C:\PruebaFunction\FunConverter__init**.py", line 32, in main
>       word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')   File "C:\PruebaFunction\ConvEnv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client__init__.py",
>   line 250, in CreateObject
>       return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)   File "C:\PruebaFunction\ConvEnv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client__init__.py",
>   line 188, in _manage
>       obj = GetBestInterface(obj)   File "C:\PruebaFunction\ConvEnv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client__init__.py",
>   line 112, in GetBestInterface
>       interface = getattr(mod, itf_name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting docx to pdf with pure python (on linux, without libreoffice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982064/converting-docx-to-pdf-with-pure-python-on-linux-without-libreoffice)

Comment: I am running on windows

Answer (score 2):

U can try lib win32com to finish that

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import  os
from win32com import client
#pip instatll win32com
def doc2pdf(doc_name, pdf_name):
    """
    :word to pdf
    :param doc_name word file name
    :param pdf_name to_pdf file name
    """
    try:
        word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
        if os.path.exists(pdf_name):
            os.remove(pdf_name)
        worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name,ReadOnly = 1)
        worddoc.SaveAs(pdf_name, FileFormat = 17)
        worddoc.Close()
        return pdf_name
    except:
        return 1
if __name__=='__main__':
    doc_name = "f:/test.doc"
    ftp_name = "f:/test.pdf"
    doc2pdf(doc_name, ftp_name)
```

Comment: I get an error at line: "        word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
"
TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "http" for Python type "NoneType"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python library `docx2pdf` which internally uses `win32com`: https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf

Install:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Usage:

```
from docx2pdf import convert
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

As you mentioned, this approach does require having Microsoft Office installed.

Disclaimer: I wrote this library and command line tool.

Comment: If you run in loop, converting multiple `.docx` files, it gets struck after converting a few files.

Comment: @cph_sto Are you running on Windows or macOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Words for Python to [convert DOCX and other document formats to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/convert-a-document-to-pdf/). Code is simple - load a document and save it as PDF:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("in.docx")
doc.save("out.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self-contained example, which, similar to the others, requires Word to be installed.

```py
# pip install python-docx 

import os
import tempfile
import docx
import win32com.client as win32com_client
import pywintypes

PDF_FILEPATH = "status_report.pdf"


def save_docx_pdf(docx_object, filepath):
    # Create a Microsoft Word Application object
    try:
        word = win32com_client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    except pywintypes.com_error as e:
        raise AssertionError(f"Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer: {e}")

    # Just get a file descriptor and temp filepath
    fd, temppath = tempfile.mkstemp()
    # Must close to avoid PermissionError in next step
    os.close(fd)

    # Save the Word document
    docx_object.save(temppath)

    # Open the Word document
    word_doc = word.Documents.Open(temppath, ReadOnly=1)

    # Remove the existing file in case it already exists
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        os.remove(filepath)

    # Save the document as PDF (it NEEDS the abspath)
    # (FileFormat 17 is for PDF)
    word_doc.SaveAs(os.path.abspath(filepath), FileFormat=17)
    # Close our temporary Word document
    # (False means do not save changes)
    word_doc.Close(False)
    # Delete the temporary Word document
    os.remove(temppath)


##########################################

# Create a new document
docx_object = docx.Document()

save_docx_pdf(docx_object, PDF_FILEPATH)
```